# VBA Excel - Take range of few columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to read data from columns by for loop. It should starts on B2 and ends on G2. I want to read B2 value as a string, and put another value to G2 cell. I use cellValue variable as Range type, and deviceName to take out this value of cell (cells(1) because first cell in this cellValue range).

However I have got error like this:
"Invalid procedure call or argument"

```
 For Row = 2 To rows
        cellValue = ActiveSheet.Cells("B" & CStr(Row) & ":" & "G" & CStr(Row))
        deviceName = cellValue.Cells(1)
        
        // my code...
 Next Row
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Cells("B" & CStr(Row) & ":" & "G" & CStr(Row))`: Here you should use `Range(...)` and not `Cells(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Couldn’t find any obvious flaws above, but I changed it up a bit. This should work. I’m using Cells and only numbers for the iteration, rather than casting with Cstr.

```
Dim ws as worksheet
Dim fRow as Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(“Sheet1”)

With ws
  fRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,6).end(xlUp).Row
End with


For row = 2 to fRow
  cellValue = ws.Range(Cells(2,row),Cells(6,row)).Value
deviceName = CellValue

Next row
```

Answer (score 0):

Post an example for a range.

```
Sub test()
    Dim cellValue As Range, vDB As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim deviceName
    
    r =  ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'Set r to suit your situation.
    'Row and rows are similar to reserved words in visual basic, so we don't recommend them.
    For i = 2 To r
        'Because range is an object, you must use the set statement.
        Set cellValue = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & CStr(i) & ":" & "G" & CStr(i))
        'same code above
        Set cellValue = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i & ":" & "G" & i) '<~~ When it is made by connecting letters and numbers, it becomes a letter.
        Set cellValue = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i, "G" & i)     '<~~ The first part of the comma is the first cell in the region, and the last part is the last cell in the region.
        Set cellValue = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Resize(1, 6) '<~~ 1 is rows.count, 6 is columns.count ; Change the size of the range to the size of the resize statement.
        'If the set statement is not used, it is an array of variants.
        vDB = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i & ":" & "G" & i) 'vDB is 2D array
        
        
        deviceName = cellValue.Cells(1)
        'same above code
        deviceName = cellValue.Range("a1")
        deviceName = cellValue(1)
        deviceName = cellValue.Cells(1).Offset(0, 0)
        
        'If you use arrays, vDB
        deviceName = vDB(i, 1)
    Next i

End Sub
```